# Issue testing error handling with update statement inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to understand why the code is not working. There is data in `vendorproducts` table, however no data is retrieved after executing and it is also not printing error when I am passing in `@vendor=1`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HW5UD1
    @vendor VARCHAR(64),
    @Perct DECIMAL(3,2)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE VendorProducts 
    SET paidPrice = paidPrice * (1 + @perct)
    WHERE vendor = @vendor
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   PRINT 'Error occurred while trying to update vendor products table'
   RETURN -11001
END CATCH

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT * 
FROM VendorProducts
WHERE vendor = @vendor

RETURN 0
```

Comment: Can you please format you code so its readable. Many people have done it for you in your past questions but you can't keep expecting others to to it for you.

Comment: Sure I will do it

Comment: vendor means vendor name  like DVDemporium so it is varchar

Comment: So why are you setting `vendor=1` then?

Comment: so that it returns ERROR OCCURED WHILE TRYING TO UPDATE VENDOR PRODUCTS TABLE however error is not returning.

Comment: That won't cause an error though? It just won't find a matching row to update.

Comment: remove begin try just do a normal update statement and see if you can really update

Comment: I can update there is no issue in that but I just wanted to print the error so was trying what would give error

Comment: If you want an error when the record doesn't exist you need to check whether the record exists and then throw your own error. (Or check whether any rows were updated)

Comment: do you know any scenario which will make the query go in catch block and print error. I thought if I will supply int value to vendor it should print error.

Comment: Your attempt to provide an int value fails because SQL Server automatically converts it to a string since your input parameter is a string. So all that happens is a matching record can't be found - and thats not considered an error.

Comment: I understood thanks for that . Can you think of any example which would give me error--'ERROR OCCURED WHILE TRYING TO UPDATE VENDOR PRODUCTS TABLE. I want to test it.

Comment: can you remove `return 0` line

Comment: set @Perct = 9.99 (sorry 10.0 was too large to fit, but 9.99) will throw an error.

Comment: thanks for your time but it is not printing ERROR OCCURED WHILE TRYING TO UPDATE VENDOR PRODUCTS TABLE. Its just saying error converting datatype numeric to decimal

Comment: Thats with using 9.99? Its working for me, printing the error and returning -11001. Anyway the point is to cause an overflow error as part of the update. For really easy testing just include a divide by zero in your update.

Comment: when I used 10.0 it said numeric to decimal error as my datatype id decimal(3,2)i.e just 1 digit before decimal. But 10.0 is 2 digit before decimal.

Comment: 9.99 is working for me its giving success result

Comment: OK you need to combine 9.99 as the input value, with an existing row value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment so let's start. First, learn to ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). How long did it take for you to reveal any error message? And did you post the complete message or an abbreviated version?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HW5UD1
```

Start over. This name is useless. Anyone reading your code (or the code that calls this procedure) should have some idea of what your procedure does just by reading that name.

And let's look at how you call this procedure. You first said you are calling this procedure with "@vendor=1". And a bit later you say "vendor means vendor name like DVDemporium". Something seems wrong and inconsistent here. From a schema perspective, you should have a foreign key (FK) from VendorProducts to Vendors. Do you? Do you even have a Vendors table? And is the FK column varchar or numeric? I would expect numeric since you passed a value of 1.

Next, your procedure contains a single DML statement. A single statement (update - in this case) is atomic and will either be successful or not. There is no need for a transaction. If a transaction was started before this procedure was called, you have now nested a transaction for no particular reason. Worse, you catch any error and then hide the TRUE error while throwing one of your own. You just made debugging any actual errors impossible with the hiding. Error handling is complicated in tsql - I suggest you have a read [Erland's discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html).

In your CATCH clause, you use print. Nope - don't. Do not attempt to provide "output" from a procedure (or trigger) using print. These are returned to the caller in a manner that most callers don't expect and won't process (either at all or as intended by you the developer). They simply generate extra work. It can be used for debugging purposes but should not be in production code. Because you throw an error, the caller implicitly knows that "Error occurred ..." - your print message adds nothing useful.

Your last statement in the procedure simply selects rows from the table you attempted to update. Why? If the caller has all that information when calling, this only creates extra "work". If the caller does not, then why do you assume the caller wants or needs this information. Generally speaking, your procedure should do one "thing". Just update the row(s).

So perhaps this is all an exercise for learning. Unfortunately people tend to provide working code without much explanation. Sure, you could just copy that and turn it in for a grade. But you will not have learned much (if any) and that is unfortunate. Without understanding and learning you will not develop the skills you need to be an effective developer.

And lastly, there are numerous discussions of best practices for tsql coding. These you should read and start implementing.